# Запрос для отношения belongsToMany

Tags: laravel

Есть две таблицы связанные `belongsToMany`

1)

```
class Project extends Model
{
    public function alerts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Alert');
    }
}
```

2)

```
class Alert extends Model
{
    public function projects()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Project');
    }
}
```

3) Таблица `alert_project`

```
    Schema::create('alerts', function (Blueprint $table) {

        $table->string('alert')->nullable();
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('alert_project', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('alert_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('alert_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('alerts')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->integer('project_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('project_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('projects')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Необходимо написать запрос в представлении для вывода значения поля `alert` через определённый `project`. Вот например как-то так:

```
 @foreach ($projects as $project)
                  <tr id="{{$project->id}}" class="{{$project->alerts()->alert}}">

                        <td data-name="id" class="id">{{$project->id}}</td>
                        <td data-name="du_id" class="edit du_id">{{$project->du_id}}</td>
                   </tr>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как вытащить значение `$project->alerts()->alert` в этом цикле.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В документации сразу приведен [пример](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many):

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * The roles that belong to the user.
     */
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
    }
}
```

После определения отношения вы можете получить доступ к ролям пользователя, используя динамическое свойство roles:

```
$user = App\User::find(1);

foreach ($user->roles as $role) {
    //
}
```

Конструкция

```
$user->roles
```

То же самое что и

```
$user->roles()->get()
```

У Вас у каждого проекта может быть несколько алертов. Вы написали код как-будто хотите вытащить один alert для каждого проекта, это не правильно.

```
$project->alerts()->alert // ???
```

После того как Вы написали `alerts()` со скобками это уже идет Query/Builder в котором нет свойства alert.